# When using gt5 in my home directory I get a blank page

Tags: linux

When using [gt5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/) in various directories on my system (including my home directory) I get blank results.

If I limit the max-depth enough, I get results. For example, in my home directory 'gt5 --max-depth 2' produces a listing, while 'gt5 --max-depth 3' produces a blank page.

I've noticed that the temporary html file that gets created in tmp (such as '/tmp/gt5.9035.kJVM08Y9/gt5.html' is a zero-byte file.

I can successfully do a du in the same directory (which is what I thought gt5 was using), so I'm not sure what to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with mawk (the awk installed by default with Ubuntu Karmic). I opened a launchpad bug for it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mawk/+bug/537616). After switching to gawk, everything is working as expected.